# Calculating number of internal polygons with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a scenario where I have a number of polygons, many of which have polygons wholly contained within them, or which overlap them. For each polygon, I wish to count all the contained and overlapping polygons within it to give a single count per polygon. I am using PostgreSQL/PostGIS. I thought I could do this with ST_Relate, specifically using ST_Relate(a.geom,b.geom,'2********') as I think that should give me overlapping interiors. This mostly works but, as shown below, a couple of the results aren't what I expected. All polygons have been generated using QGIS with snapping functions on, so there should not be any spurious overlaps, other than those clearly visible.

Where am I going wrong and what should the correct ST_Relate expression be? I am struggling to get my head around this DE9IM.

[image]

Just to be clear, my code is

```
create table output as 
        select count(*), a.geom, a.id
        from my_data a, my_data b
        where a.id < b.id and ST_Relate(a.geom,b.geom,'2********')
                       group by a.geom, a.id;
```

Comment: The DE-9IM pattern is correct to find overlapping or contained polygons.  My first thought is that there might be tiny overlaps which aren't visible.  Can you post some data to confirm this?

Comment: There shouldn't be any overlaps because snapping was on. But test data is available here https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5qup7x223jqhxoh/AAC5s3B0ZIYVmNbqX8S1dlz-a?dl=0. Any pointers gratefully received.

Answer (score 3):

The data you provided confirms that the query is doing exactly what it should.

Here's the polygons labelled with Id:
[image: Polygons with Id]

The query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), a.id
  FROM my_data a, my_data b
  WHERE a.id < b.id AND ST_Relate(a.geom,b.geom,'2********')
  GROUP BY a.id;
```

gives:

```
 count | id 
-------+----
     5 |  1
     1 |  3
     1 |  4
     4 |  6
     1 |  7
     1 |  9
     1 | 11
     1 | 13
     2 | 16
     2 | 19
```

- Polygon 4 has a count of 1 because it overlaps Polygon 22 (due to a vertex in 22 which lies inside 4, as seen here with the topology magnified)
  [image: Magnified overlap between 4 and 22]
- Polygon 14 does not appear in the result set because the overlap is already counted for Polygon 13 (due to the `a.id < b.id` condition)

Comment: Wow. That's unexpected. I ran the same check by zooming in in QGIS and, in my version, they all appear correctly aligned. Clearly something is not showing up right on my system. Thank you for that. At least it wasn't something obvious I'd missed. I'd checked for alignment before even submitting the question.
With respect to polygon 14, fair point, but how do I also include that one?

Comment: The overlap is very, very small, so it's not surprising it doesn't show up visually.  At some point we hope to provide spatial predicates that accept a tolerance value, which will solve this problem.

Comment: To report the number of overlaps for Polygon 14 (and others) you can change the condition to `a.id != b.id`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your `ST_Relate` matrix because I have not read all the doc, but if you filter your result with `a.id < b.id`, it seems logical that you have the current result: when id 1 relates to id 2 and 2 relates to 1, only the smaller id 1 will have a line with this filter, so the other polygon will not have any line.

You should remove this filter and I think it will be better.

Also, depending of the matrix, you can have boundaries included, maybe that's your left issue.